# Сделать снимок с камеры

Tags: камера, android, java

В коде есть строчки

```
camera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() {
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {.....делаем фото.....}
```

Дальше идёт код, который не связан с камерой. Различные действия. И в конце кода открываю другой layout.

Проблема в том, что обрабатывается код который не связан с камерой, открытие layout.. И только затем обрабатывается `Callback`
Так как новый layout перекрывает `surfaceView` снимок сделать не получается. А мне он нужен =)

Фрагмент кода :

```
try {   
   GetPic();
} catch (IOError e) {}  
   Thread.currentThread();
   Thread.sleep(500);
   Intent intent = new Intent() .setClass(MainActivity.this, mail.class);                     
   startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
   TextForFile = TextForFile + "Photo_" + date2+ ".jpg"+";";

   //запись текстового файла
   try {
      OutputStream ToRecordsFile;
      ToRecordsFile=new FileOutputStream(photoFile + File.separator+"r.csv",true);
      OutputStreamWriter sw=new OutputStreamWriter(ToRecordsFile);
      sw.write(TextForFile);
      sw.close();//Закрыли 
   } catch (IOException e) {
   Log.e("MyError", "Не создался writer", e);
}
    //запись текстового файла
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Функция GetPic() :

```
private void GetPic() {
            try {
            camera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                    fos.write(data);
                    fos.close();
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }}
                 });
            } catch(Exception e) {}
```

Comment: @selgkos вы сами то поняли свой вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

> код, который не связан с камерой. Различные действия. И в конце кода открываю другой Лайяут.

Так и выполняйте эти "различные действия" после вызова `onPictureTaken`. И новую `Activity` запускайте так же после отработки колбэка камеры.

Comment: В коде они выполняются после. Если смотреть отладчиком, - колбак отрабатывается в конце процедуры. 
Пока помогла небольшая пауза после onPictureTaken. Как ни странно.

Comment: Как я понял из вашего вопроса, код, выполняющий "различные действия" находится сразу после `camera.takePicture(…)`. А вообще, покажите код. Сдаётся мне, что вы делаете что-то неверно, раз уж дело дошло до костылей в виде "паузы после onPictureTaken".